# How do I properly work with the grid

Tags: modeling, scale, snapping

[image]

I'm working in centimeters because that is what UE4's unit scale is. My problem is when I scale a wall segment to be [304.8cm or 10ft] I'm no longer aligned to the grid properly. Am I going to have to scale my wall segment to be [274.32cm or 9ft] to stay aligned to the grid and just make a separate piece that is [30.48cm or 1ft] to get the 10ft the wall i want? The building I want to model is 30ft wide so i was attempting to make 10ft wide modular wall segments. I'm new to all of this so sorry if this question is dumb.

Comment: If you set unit system to imperial, the grid will be in feet but internally Blender will keep metric units.

Answer (score 1):

Just choose *imperial* in the unit setting panel. By doing this, the grid and all length system will give a proper behavior if you use imperial.

[image]

There is no different between imperial and metric. But if you want to cooperate with others, start in metric unit will be a better choice in my opinion.

Comment: So working with imperial will give me proper scaling results in UE4?. I thought working with imperial and then exporting to UE4 would give janky scaling results due to unreal engine using a metric based system?.

Comment: @FenderBlender All depend on how 3D modeling tool treat scaling. In Blender, the unit you see in metric and imperial is just a scope. The real numeric value inside the 3-dimension won't change if you adjust those scaling setting inside unit panel. If your still concern about it, switch back to metric before exporting it to UE4. You could also adjust the scaling option inside the exporter panel.